# USB C as audio input?

Tags: sound, android, usb-c

I have a laptop running Ubuntu 18.04, and I was wondering if it is possible to connect to my android phone using USB-C and use it as an audio source? That way I could play my phone's audio over the Computer's Speakers or AUX jack.

Comment: If the phone recognizes the laptop as an external audio device, then yes, and if not, then no. I am not sure what it has to do with USB C or with Ubuntu.

Comment: I figured it would have to do with software on the computer's side.